# I created a plugin with 'view page' that uses MYSQL + PHP. When I use wp_insert_post(), it turns everything to HTML

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql, wp-load.php

I created a custom plugin. The plugin has a **view log page.** Here is my **viewpage_template.php**. First part is a query. The second part is a PHP for loop to present the data in a table.

```
<?php
// viewpage_template.php

global $wpdb;

// Get User ID
$journal_author = get_current_user_id();

// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "sg_entries";
$prompt_table = $wpdb->prefix . "sg_prompts";

// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE journal_author = $journal_author" );
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $prompt_table",ARRAY_A);
$prompt_text_db = $result
    
?>

<?php 
    
// Simple table database
    
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->journal_date;?></td>
        <td><?php 
     $journal_day_of_year = $retrieved_data->journal_prompt_ID;                            
      echo $prompt_text_db[$journal_day_of_year -1]["journal_prompt_text"];
      ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $retrieved_data->journal_content;?></td>
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo "view"; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo "edit"; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
```

In my main plugin, I created a function using wp_insert_post to create a page in WordPress that runs when someone installs my plugin. The page creates a *static* page of my **view log page** instead of a page that runs PHP code each time for a user. So, no matter if you're logged in or a different user, you see the contents of user id #1 (admin, me).

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate2' );
    function myplugin_activate2() {
   //create a variable to specify the details of page

        ob_start();
        include('viewpage_template.php');
        $journal_logs = ob_get_clean();
        
        $post = array(     
                 'post_content'   => $journal_logs, //content of page
                 'post_title'     =>'logs-journal', //title of page
                 'post_status'    =>  'publish' , //status of page - publish or draft
                 'post_type'      =>  'page'  // type of post
);
        wp_insert_post( $post ); // creates page
}
```

I am wondering... 1) why does wp_insert_post retrieve my user id (admin id #1)? 2) Why is my view page a static page, instead of a dynamic-data page? I am guessing that wp_insert_post converts all my php from my template page to HTML? I want this page to run PHP code.

Comment: This isn’t how WordPress works. If you want a dynamic page then you need to create a page template and assign it to a page: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This might be it.